# Selecting database model for comma separated dataset

Tags: mysql, database, nosql

In my project I have comma separated data like this, (other attributes also exist). Basically, a movie dataset having different information related to that movie. ***For argument sake, data could be a million.* Intend to do semantic search on reviews, synopsis, plot as well.**

[image]

The interface would have simply help people to filter the Movie list of their choices based on their preferences (selections like year=2011,Actor=Tim AND Saw etc).

The interface includes filters which take input conditions for (Movie,Year,Actor,Music etc). These filters are dynamically populated from database and are sorted based on count and have a corresponding count beside the label. Upon selection of a filter, other filter values also dynamically change. 
*(like, in filter list of 'countries' if I selected CA, then filter list of 'Actors' would have actors from country CA only and are sorted based on count)*

For this to happen in MySql, I think, we need to normalise data into multiple tables having a common ID. But, when number of columns have more such comma separated data and with such a large dataset, With number of JOIN operations doesn't it slow down the interface?

Is there any alternative? Am I missing something? Or should I look for options outside MySql? If so, what are they? Can NoSql be of help?

Comment: You know what to do (normalize the data).  MySQL will handle performance on this very reasonably, assuming you have indexes on the fields you are searching on.  Databases are designed to do joins efficiently.

Comment: As you observe, with proper [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) this would be totally fine in MySQL, or any other RDBMS for that matter. For performance you'll need to benchmark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are thinking of your data in a very relational way, so I would recommend you to [normalize your data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) and use a relational database.

Don't worry too much about the performance of JOINs. As long as the joins are on equality of pre-defined secondary keys, and all search-able fields have indexes, the performance should be acceptable.

When you really want to look at a No-SQL solution, you could look at graph-based databases like [Neo4j](http://www.neo4j.org/) (one [online demo](http://www.neo4j.org/learn/cypher) is surprisingly close to your use-case).